# R: computing the initial slope from a graph

Tags: r

I have a curve produced by the code below in `R/Sweave`:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{Sweave}  %%%%%%
 \SweaveOpts{eps=TRUE}

 \begin{document}

<<echo=FALSE, results=hide>>=
test.frame<-data.frame(ratio= c(0.0, 144.321, 159.407, 178.413, 202.557), value= c(0, 0.84, 0.8925, 0.945, 0.9975))
@


<<echo=FALSE,results=hide,eval=TRUE>>=
postscript('doudou.eps',
           width=7, height=6,
           colormodel="cmyk",
           family = "ComputerModern",
           horizontal = FALSE,
           onefile=FALSE,
           paper = "special",
           encoding = "TeXtext.enc",
           pagecentre=FALSE)

with(test.frame,plot(ratio, value, ylab= "Hello",
                               xlab="Wonderful",
                               type="o",        
                               bty="o",         
                               lty="solid",     
                               lwd=3,            
                               pch=1,            
                               xaxp=c(0, 200, 4),  
                               xlim=c(0,200),
                               yaxt = "n",         
                               main=" My curve"))

axis(2,seq(0,1, by=0.5), las=2,cex=3,cex.lab=2,cex.axis=1.5,cex.main=2)

dev.off()
@

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{doudou.eps}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

The curve has a `x = +\sqrt(y)` behaviour. I need to draw the maximum slope from the first point of the curve that is tangent to the initial curve slope. How to calculate the parameters with `R` so that I get the equation of the line?

An approximate solution is to find a best fit line but then the initial point (0, 0) of the dataset does not form part of the fitted line (we get a y-intercept other than zero).

Thanks a lot...

Comment: This question is not related to Sweave. Please reduce it to a minimal self-contained R-Sample.

Comment: In addition to Dieter's comment: what do you mean by "initial slope" and "maximum slope"?   If you just want to find a linear fit with forced origin, read the help file for `lm()` .

Comment: I like that you are taking mich time in learning Sweave, but please do realize that Sweave is just the combination of R and LaTeX. If you have a question on the R codes alone it is best to only supply R codes in the question. To obtain these from a noweb document (Rnw; snw) you can run Stangle on it in exactly the same way you run Sweave. See also `?Stangle` in R.

Comment: @ Henry has answered my question. Thanks a lot for your comments guys. I shall try to separate R and Sweave/LaTeX issues in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your graph has five points: one at 0 and four between 144 and 203, so I don't think you can say much about behaviour near 0.

```
test.frame<-data.frame(ratio= c(0.0, 144.321, 159.407, 178.413, 202.557), 
                       value= c(0, 0.84, 0.8925, 0.945, 0.9975))
with(test.frame,plot(ratio, value, ylab= "Hello", xlab="Wonderful", type="o",
                     bty="o", lty="solid", lwd=3, pch=1, xaxp=c(0, 200, 4),  
                     xlim=c(0,200), yaxt = "n", main=" My curve") )
axis(2,seq(0,1, by=0.5), las=2,cex=3,cex.lab=2,cex.axis=1.5,cex.main=2)
```

[image]

You can get the slope of the first segment with

```
> with(test.frame, (value[2]-value[1])/(ratio[2]-ratio[1]) )
[1] 0.005820359
```

Or you can put a line through all the points restricted to going through the origin with

```
> with(test.frame, lm(value ~ ratio - 1 ) )
Coefficients:
   ratio  
0.005325
```

Or you can take your square-root function, which I think (but am not sure) you might intend to be

```
> with(test.frame, lm(value ~ sqrt(ratio) - 1 ) )
Coefficients:
sqrt(ratio)  
    0.07037
```

but in this case, note that the gradient of the tangent of `y = 0.07 sqrt(x)` is infinite at 0.

Comment: @ Henry. Thank you for your clear presentation and answer. It is always good to learn from a different perspective. 1vote up